# Angular - Inner custom component "invalid" state not being propagated

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, validation

I have been trying to create custom input components, which will isolate their own validation logic, messages, labels, etc. The problem is that, if I have validations such as "required" or "email" on my inner input, the form that encapsulates this custom component is ignoring it when calculating its validity.

For example:

```
<form novalidate #myForm="ngForm">
    <p>Form is valid: {{myForm.valid}}</p>
    <div>
        <my-input name="custom" [(ngModel)]="somedata"></my-input>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the custom component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  template: `
        <label>Inner custom component input (doesn't make form valid)</label>
        <input required type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (blur)="onBlur()" ngDefaultControl/>
  `,
  providers: [MakeProvider(MyInputComponent)],
})
export class MyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
   /** Bloat. Check plnkr below for more **/
}
```

For a more complete example, I have created this plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/p0KfBIwYwibL0QkBf1xo?p=preview

When the plain input (check plnkr) is empty, the form is considered invalid. So far, so good. You can fill it, and the form is considered to be valid.
But the inner input inside the custom component is required as well, and the form is ignoring this fact.
I'm not sure of what I've been doing wrong. Maybe you can shed some light on this issue for me?

Thank you in advance!